# Iterating through a class python

Tags: python

I have a vector class that I need to iterate through.  The class contains a list variable.  I need to iterate through the class.

Im not sure how I would do this.  I need to use `__iter__` and its suggested that I use `yield`, here is the result that I want:

```
[x*2 for x in Vector([3,3.25,"foo"])]
[6, 6.5, 'foofoo']
```

Iter should return an object that can iterate over the elements of the vector.
How would I go about doing this I never used `__iter__` before.

Comment: Can i recommend not overwriting the default class object with your parameter name? Not your problem, but probably not helping anybody

Comment: Also what is that bitwise or doing on line 5? Nothing good I bet

Comment: same with using `|` for a logical or.  Python has the keyword `or`

Comment: didnt know that, new to python will replace with or

Comment: Shouldn't matter here since booleans can evaluate to 0 or 1 anyways.

Comment: Note that `isinstance(obj,long) or isinstance(obj,int)` can be replaced by : `isinstance(obj, (long, int))`. Also you make `l` a class-variable (line 2), which is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically :

```
def __iter__(self):
    for elt in self.l:
        yield elt
```